# custom menu based on TabsAdapter with SherlockFragmentActivity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

i am trying to add a custom menu based on TabsAdapter with SherlockFragmentActivity.

[image: what i want to do]

currently i have tab menu with 4 tabs,
i want to add an custom image (marked as green circle) that overlay the entire menu and the tab

any idea how it can be done?

Comment: i would like alsow an other designed not based on tabsadupter

Comment: found a work around :)
got the layout of the tab2. added margin laft of 1\5 width of screen:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a solution:

add 4 tabs to TabsAdapter
add a layout margin to second tab:

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int heigth = mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height;
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((width / 5), heigth));
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((width / 5), heigth));

    View currentView = mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams currentLayout = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) currentView.getLayoutParams();
    currentLayout.setMargins(0, 0, width / 5, 0);

    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((width / 5), heigth));
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((width / 5), heigth));
```